# Lightbox gallery not working with meteor.js

Tags: javascript, meteor, lightbox

#### Did the steps

1. Copied **lightbox.css** ,**lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js** into my meteor project directory
   *client/templates/layouts*
2. **image.html**

   `<a href="{{url}}"  data-lightbox="{{category}}" class="cbp-caption
   cbp-singlePageInline" data-title="World Clock Widget<br>by Paul
   Flavius Nechita">`
3. **DefaultLayout.html**  is my project homepage located in  *client/templates/layouts*

   Here in body `<script src="lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js">< /script>` included
   Here in head `<link rel="stylesheet" href="lightbox.css">`

But still when image is clicked it loads in traditional way.
There is no lightbox gallery?
Please, suggest a way to integrate lightbox with meteor.js application.

Answer (score 0):

you need your lightbox js file to be loaded after all DOM elements in the body are loaded and with Meteor it isn't that simple. You can try with: https://atmospherejs.com/juliancwirko/s-image-box for simple image popups. It is prepared for Meteor